# empty dashboard for custom role

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets, dashboard, user-roles

I setup a custom post type `employee` with an `agent` role that mimics an `author` role for this particular post type, and so far everything is working fine, except that when I created a `test` user and granted it an `agent` role, the dashboard that `test` sees is empty as in:

[image]

I was hoping it would be something like what an `author` user would see, like:

[image]

Could anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [support forum thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/edit_posts-tied-to-right-now-widget?replies=2) has both an explanation and a code snippet that you might be able to work up into a solution.

The "Right Now" widget is tied to the `edit_posts` capability. I don't know about the incoming links widget or quick post widget, but I'd guess it's the same issue of either requiring `edit_posts` or another similar post-specific capability.

Comment: sweet. def'ly one good direction to point me to. will work on it and let you know what happens. thanks, @mrwweb